# Package for solving large scale optimization

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, heuristics

I am looking for a package that be strong for solving large scale optimization problem via heuristic method.

For global optimizations, I use GAMS/CPlex and for heuristic methods I used MATLAB optimization toolbox but it is very slow

any idea?

Comment: How large? What kind of problems?

Comment: Andreas, I am dealing with Integer programming and Mixed integer Programming 
In optimization I have around 50,000,000 rows

Comment: You might look at [scip.zib.de](http://scip.zib.de) .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (open source, java). It supports many construction heuristics and metaheuristics. It has been successfully applied on [very large datasets](http://blog.athico.com/2012/06/roadef-2012-first-results-for-dataset-b.html) (`50 000` variables, `10 000` values per variable, search space of `10 000 ^ 50 000`).

Comment: Geoffrey, 
the number of my deliveries /day is around 400, how can I model it ghraphically?

Comment: There's no graphic support out-of-the-box currently (it's planned though in the long run). Companies usually want to build a custom UI anyway, and integrate that with their existing applications.